# Trying to understand AJAX jQuery basics

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm a newb with jQuery and AJAX and have a simple function below where I'm querying a server. What I would like to do is iterate through the data I retrieve and store it in an array, or pass it to another function to deal with: Fetch(DealWith) I'm presuming? I don't quite understand what form my data is in now or how to access it. Any tips?

```
 function Fetch(){
          $.ajax({
              url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
              dataType: "json",
              success: function(data){   
        }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're exactly right with that code, there - just don't forget to specify your method. (it defaults to GET, I think)

To iterate through the response you'd do something like this:

```
for(i in data){
   console.log(data[i]);
   console.log(data[i][otherData]); 
}
```

But depending on what you're doing, you may be better off letting the server-side code handle your iterations.

But you're on the right track -! don't be afraid to play around with it a little and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

JSON response that you specify as data type is a native, regular - and most convenient - JavaScript Object. Getting started with JS objects may be confusing, but it's really worthwhile.

In any case, you can do with a JS object anything you can do with an array ( a set of key-value pair ) - so may not even need to iterate through that. Eg, a property called propertyName can be accessed as data.propertyName or data['propertyName'] + you can do vastly more with an object.

In your example, you'll probably want to return the data var in your success handler:

```
function Fetch(){
      $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.parse.com/1/classes/chats",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data){ 
            return data;
      }
    })
}
```